# How to delete a slot of an element in a list in R with lappy

Tags: r, lapply

So i have a long list of objects that each have a slot that i want to delete. Specifically they are storing the data in a duplicate manner. But the reason why shouldn't matter.

My main question regards what is "proper" way of doing this. So here is the set up:

```
q <- list()
q$useless <- rnorm(100)
q$useful <- rnorm(100)

SampleList <- list(q,q,q)
```

So I have a list of identical objects(or at least identical look objects). I want to delete the useless slot. why, because it is useless to me.

I can do with a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(SampleList)){
   SampleList[[i]]$useless <- NULL
}
```

But why doesn't the lapply() version work. So guess the question is what do I not get about lapply.

```
lapply(SampleList, function(x){print(x$useless) })
SampleList<- lapply(SampleList, function(x){x$useless <- NULL }) #NO WORK
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function inside the lapply isn't returning anything so it defaults to returning the result of your assignment.  You need to return the modified object for your version to work

```
SampleList <- lapply(SampleList, function(x){x$useless <- NULL; x})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple `lapply` version

```
SampleList <- lapply(1:3, function(x, i) x[[i]]$useful,  x=SampleList)
```

or even this one which is simpler than the previous one

```
lapply(SampleList, function(x) x$useful)
```

Both instructions select only `useful` elements. Instead of replacing the useless by `NULL` this call just select those which are `useful`.

Comment: Or even `lapply(SampleList, "[[", "useful")`